# Equivalent to JasperReports in dotnet

Tags: .net, report

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) is cool with JAVA web apps.

CrystalReports is not equivalent to it :D

what tool can we use in asp.net web applications ?

Comment: what features, exactly, out of the jasper reports library do you want to use? chances are there are some good frameworks out there that are not exactly equivalent in every aspect, but that'll still do the part you're looking for just fine.

Comment: chances are, also, that a lot of the people who know a great deal about different .net tools out there, does not have sufficient java knowledge to know exactly which tool best fits your need, unless you describe your needs in further detail.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to use JasperReports by using the JasperReports Server product along with it's Web Services APIs, HTTP APIs with iFrames, etc.  Short of buying something overpriced from Microsoft, I don't think you will